# How to create a service with dependency to a wifi adapter in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, service, wifi, adapter

We are creating a service which needs to extract the MAC address of the wifi adapter. This is done by `CreateService` for the type `SERVICE_AUTO_START` with dependency to group `+NetworkProvider`.

It works reliably for the startup of the system. However if Windows awakes after the sleep mode, the service starts right before the wifi adapter is recognized and therefor it fails to read its MAC address.

Is there any sort of dependency which can be specified to `CreateService` in order to wait for the wifi adapter?

Currently the workaround is to set the service to restart on fail which of course is an ugly solution.

Comment: Why not simply poll the network configuration and compare for differences. Or even just ask Windows to notify you when the network adapters are changed? This sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: What stops you from tryiing to get the address again after a specified time? Like @RemyLebeau says just poll until your read is succesful.  (And block incoming calls until the address is ok)

Comment: The service is a 3rd party application on which we have no influence. So we can't make it polling for any state.
The question is there is the ability to configure a dependency which makes the service control manager waiting for the startup of the wifi adapter.

Comment: @AchimSchön AFAIK, there is no 1 single dependency for this. Can you set the 3rd party service to manual-start and then make your own service that validates the adapter before then starting the 3rd party service?